# Creating setback buffer for lines using QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I've attached a little diagram showing what I want to do. Using the directional buffer tool results in the bottom left output, which is not what I want, which is the center one.

Regular buffer tools result in the diagram on the right, which would have been one step towards the solution I'd have gone for: using the coastlines shapefile as the other layer in an intersection operation that would result in what I want.

[image: quick MS Paint Diagram]